# Are A/B testing problems intrinsically a multiple testing problem?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, ab-test

Can we convert any A/B testing problem into a multiple testing problem?

Comment: What is the context? If you change one button and check for its effect, then you are performing one test. So no, A/B testing is not intrinsically a multiple testing problem.

Comment: @FransRodenburg, why not make that an official answer? Although this question is rather sparse, it could be answered, & that would be it, AFAICT.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I was not sure it would be sufficient information for an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on the context of using A/B testing:

If you change one button and check for its effect, then you are performing one test. So A/B testing is not intrinsically a multiple testing problem.

Comment: Ok. If we were to perform multiple A/B testing, potentially with a large number of features, would that be intrinsically a multiple testing problem?

Comment: Or in the case where companies run a sequence of A/B tests over time.

Comment: If you test $p$ features from a single experiment for significance, then you need to correct for $p$ tests. You could think of Bonferroni, or FDR if the former is too conservative. If you perform a new A/B test with new observations, then no correction is applied for having performed one previously on a different dataset.

Comment: Thanks. I'm currently working on a online FDR control paper, that's why I'm thinking of a multiple A/B testing application.